# How to put this piece of code into an AsyncTask or a Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Im new in threads and AsyncTask's and I would like to know how can I run the following code in the background:

I have this method which checks if you have an active internet conection, what Im trying to do is to show a ProgressDialog before calling the method and dismissing the dialog when succeed or fail:

Oncreate:

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title","dialog message", true);
            if(isOnline()){}else{}
```

My method.

```
public Boolean isOnline() {

        try {
            Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.karlol.com");
            int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
            boolean reachable = (returnVal==0);
            canshowview = true;
            progress.dismiss();
            return reachable;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The method works well (It tells me if there's an active internet connection) the problem is that the AlertDialog is not working as I would like to, so Im pretty sure if I put this into a Thread or AsynTask it should work as I want.

UPDATE:
I use ConnectivityManager to check if the user us connected to a network, but this does not verify the connection

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
              = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Using `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()` is a much more efficient way to find whether the device is online or not.

Comment: I update my answer with some aditional info related to that, please If theres a better way to check the ACTIVE internet connection with ConnectivityManager let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You should also check `activeNetworkInfo.isAvailable()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that this is the best way to get the result you are looking for but here it is

```
(AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>(){

   protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
   try {
        Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.karlol.com");
        int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
        boolean reachable = (returnVal==0);
        canshowview = true;
        progress.dismiss();
        return reachable;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return false
}


   protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) 
{
    /// do something here
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}).execute()
```

I would look at using as a better solution to your problem

```
 public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried the second piece of code, Is working as what I have, does not checks the connection

Comment: are you sure you have a connection? is that www.karlol.com working?

Comment: Yes, I tested your first piece of code, the AsyncTask proposal and apparently its working fine, I need to make some test in other devices but it worked good.